# Sorting a list using a hashmap by values then keys

Tags: java

I'm given a list of numbers that I'm trying to sort by frequency, if the frequency is the same, they should then be sorted in ascending order. I first create a map of the list, with the keys representing each number and the values representing their frequency, and then use a comparator to sort from there. I've tried this a few different ways and am completely stuck. please help and sorry for any poor syntax in advance. With past code I've gotten a result that would not sort by key if values were the same, but now I am just getting an error.

```
items = [42, 5, 17, 42, 42, 17, 5, 42]

public static void sortByFreq(List<Integer> items) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> counter = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        if (counter.containsKey(items.get(i))) {
            counter.put(items.get(i), counter.get(items.get(i)) + 1);
        } else {
            counter.put(items.get(i), 1);
        }
    }
    Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> comp = new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> a, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> b) {

            if (a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue()) == 0) {
                return a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey());
            }
            else {
                return a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue());
            }
        }
    };

    Collections.sort(items, comp);

Expected Result : [42, 42, 42, 42, 5, 5, 17, 17]
Error received: java: no suitable method found for sort(java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>,java.util.Comparator<java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer>>)
    method java.util.Collections.<T>sort(java.util.List<T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method java.util.Collections.<T>sort(java.util.List<T>,java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: java.lang.Integer
        upper bounds: java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer>,java.lang.Object)
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to the `Comparator` should be `Integer`s since that is what the `List` contains. You would need to call `counter.get` to get the frequencies to compare. This can be accomplished more simply with `Comparator.comparing` and `.thenComparing`.

```java
Map<Integer, Long> counter = items.stream().collect(
                  Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
items.sort(Comparator.comparing((Integer i) -> counter.get(i))
     .reversed().thenComparing(Function.identity()));
```

Comment: I think frequency should be descending.

Comment: @shmosel Good call. I missed that.

Comment: Does `counter::get` not work?

Comment: @shmosel Unfortunately not. The type can't be inferred in that case (unless it's written as `Comparator.<Integer, Long>comparing(counter::get)`).

Comment: Right, you could probably do `Comparator.<Integer>comparingLong(counter::get)` or something, but that's the kind of ugliness I was trying to avoid in my answer.

Comment: @shmosel I just saw your answer. Nice approach! It is currently removing duplicates, though; you could fix that by replacing the last `map` with `.flatMap(e -> Collections.nCopies(e.getValue().intValue(), e.getKey()).stream())`.

Comment: Good point, totally missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Count each value, then sort by the count

```
List<Integer> items = List.of( 42, 5, 17, 42, 42, 17, 5, 42 );
Map<Integer, Long> counts = items.stream()
    .collect( Collectors.toMap(
        Function.identity(),
        v -> 1L,
        Long::sum
    ));
List<Integer> sorted = items.stream()
    .sorted( Comparator
        .comparingLong( a -> counts.getOrDefault( a, 0L ) )
        .reversed()
    )
    .toList();
System.out.println( sorted );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it with streams:

```
List<Integer> sorted = items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(n -> n, Collectors.summingInt(n -> 1)))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .map(e -> Collections.nCopies(e.getValue(), e.getKey()))
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The first `collect` produces a frequency map. Then we sorted the entries by key and then again by value. This results in a stream sorted primarily by value (i.e. frequency) and secondarily by key. It's equivalent to `comparing(Entry::getValue).reversed().thenComparing(Entry::getKey)`, but avoids messy generic parameters (at a slight performance cost). Finally,  we expand each entry back into a sublist of duplicates and flatten them into the final result list.